# Вопрос о использовании Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook

На [сайте](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started?locale=ru_RU) с описанием Facebook SDK определена минимальная версия Android API = 15. Можно ли использовать SDK на более младших версиях, например с 10?

Comment: Новый battlefield идет только с 4 гб ram. Можно ли запустить его на 2гб ram?

Comment: @Denis, в вашем случае вряд ли. но вот fb sdk раньше поддерживал ранние версии android api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил использовать предыдущую версию SDK. Работает.

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.5.0'
```